# How do I specify a mask for a textfield form element?

Tags: 8, forms

My use case is actually to validate a first name field to allow only alphabets and space. Is this actually the best module to use for this? I've looked at `Client-side Validation` and it looks too complex to do something as simple as this. Is there any other module to do exactly this?

I installed the [Masked Input][1] module and using the following form element.

```php
$form['codeid'] = [
  '#type'=> 'textfield', 
  '#mask' => '9999999999'
  '#attributes' => [
    'mask' => '9999999999'
  ],
].
```

Now I know how to apply a mask by adding a field to my custom entity.
(1) But how do I specify how many alphabet characters to allow, masked_input module only allows for specific number of characters to be entered in mask. Doesn't allow for regex style {2, 50} which would mean allow 50 alpa characters
(2) I can't get it to allow space character.

Comment: Have you looked at the Field Widget provided by the module?

Comment: Examine the module code and look how they do it in their field widgets: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/masked_input/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/MaskedinputFieldWidgetDefault.php#L132

Comment: I've looked through that MaskedInputFieldWidgetDefault.php class. Tried setting my element type to...```'#type' => 'masked_input'```, yet nothing happens

Comment: Field widgets can't be used in custom forms - the folks above are advising you to look at the field widget code and reproduce it in your custom form, not to change the element type away from textfield

Answer (score 0):

The module implements a field widget, which is a plugin used to render an entity field when the entity is edited or created.
You cannot use it for a generic form element as the one implemented in the code shown in the question. You need to add a field to an entity (for example, user or node), choose the field type between *Text (Plain)*, *Text (Formatted)*, or *Text (Formatted, long)* and set its widget type to *Masked input*.

You could also programmatically add the entity field to an entity.